# Errno 28: No space left on device while building dockerfile

Tags: macos, docker

I am using MacOS and have about 30GB space left on my device. When I try to build a Dockerfile via `sam cli` from `aws`, I receive the following error message:

```
sam build

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .]: exit code: 1
```

Does anyone have an idea, what this is causing? I have more than enough free space on my device, so I am a bit clueless.

Thanks!

Edit: I should maybe add, that I have built the Image several times before and have never encountered this issue so far.

Comment: Re-run sam with `--debug` in case it helps clarify the root cause.

Comment: Device: the hardware might have space, but the filesystem partition used by Docker might not. The error message is misleading, but traditional.

Comment: In particular, Docker Desktop for Mac runs in a hidden VM which has its own dedicated space; you can increase it using the whale-menu settings.